# Soma de dois floats com 2 casas decimais resultando em 4 casas decimais em JAVA

Tags: sql-server, java-8, arredondamento, soma

Estou tendo um problema em JAVA onde quero armazenar resultados de cálculos apenas com 2 casas decimais no SQL Server. Para isso ao final dos meu cálculos eu realizo:

```java
Math.round(valor * 100.0f) / 100.0f;
```

para obter o valor com duas casas decimais. Depois de inserir os valores no banco estou consultando-os e realmente estão armazenados apenas com 2 casas decimais.

Quando realizo a requisição de *SELECT* eles estão vindo com 2 casas decimais também.

Mas o estranho acontece quando tento **somar** dois destes valores, o resultado desta soma dá um número com 4 casas decimais, segue imagem do debug:

[image: Resultado inesperado]

O que poderia estar acontecendo? Essa forma de arredondar está certa?

--

Além disso ao realizar a requisição de *INSERT* (só para ter certeza que o valor será inserido com 2 casas decimais):

```sql
INSERT INTO tableX (valor) values (ROUND(?,2))
```

Porém continua resultando em um número de 4 casas decimais após a soma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É assim mesmo, isso é por causa de conversões, e acontece não só no Java, mas em muitas outras linguagens, você não está fazendo errado.

Se você quiser formatar, fazer cálculos ou no seu caso, pelo que me parece está lindando dinheiro, use o formato `BigDecimal`.

Aqui tem uma thread em inglês sobre isso: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906169/weird-java-behavior-how-come-adding-doubles-with-exactly-two-decimal-places-res